# Windows AppLocker isnt blocking Apps anymore?

Tags: windows, powershell, applocker

Atm i am testing about to create rules with scripts, but that isnt the problem.. I allow aus path "*" and e.g i want to block Google Chrome, i use a exception for this usecase. But since today it doesnt work, a few weeks before it easy worked.

This is my example xml (Not my Original, but also doesnt work so there is the same...)

```
    <AppLockerPolicy Version="1">
  <RuleCollection Type="Appx" EnforcementMode="Enabled">
    <FilePublisherRule Id="c8fdd3d9-7143-4c1f-9879-a202f857d24c" Name="Allow All signed packaged apps" Description="Allows members of the Everyone group to run packaged apps that are signed." UserOrGroupSid="S-1-1-0" Action="Allow">
      <Conditions>
        <FilePublisherCondition PublisherName="*" ProductName="*" BinaryName="*">
          <BinaryVersionRange LowSection="0.0.0.0" HighSection="*" />
        </FilePublisherCondition>
      </Conditions>
    </FilePublisherRule>
  </RuleCollection>
  <RuleCollection Type="Dll" EnforcementMode="Enabled" />
  <RuleCollection Type="Exe" EnforcementMode="Enabled">
    <FilePathRule Id="37652e3e-77a5-4f50-87d6-4e5117261afd" Name="*" Description="" UserOrGroupSid="S-1-1-0" Action="Allow">
      <Conditions>
        <FilePathCondition Path="*" />
      </Conditions>
      <Exceptions>
        <FilePublisherCondition PublisherName="O=GOOGLE LLC, L=MOUNTAIN VIEW, S=CALIFORNIA, C=US" ProductName="GOOGLE CHROME" BinaryName="*">
          <BinaryVersionRange LowSection="*" HighSection="*" />
        </FilePublisherCondition>
      </Exceptions>
    </FilePathRule>
    <RuleCollectionExtensions>
      <ThresholdExtensions>
        <Services EnforcementMode="Enabled" />
      </ThresholdExtensions>
      <RedstoneExtensions />
    </RuleCollectionExtensions>
  </RuleCollection>
  <RuleCollection Type="Msi" EnforcementMode="Enabled">
    <FilePathRule Id="49471136-3ca5-4443-8d15-8f36dfb55f66" Name="*" Description="" UserOrGroupSid="S-1-1-0" Action="Allow">
      <Conditions>
        <FilePathCondition Path="*" />
      </Conditions>
    </FilePathRule>
  </RuleCollection>
  <RuleCollection Type="Script" EnforcementMode="Enabled">
    <FilePathRule Id="deca722f-798c-4615-ae4c-6bd73bfe1ba5" Name="*" Description="" UserOrGroupSid="S-1-1-0" Action="Allow">
      <Conditions>
        <FilePathCondition Path="*" />
      </Conditions>
    </FilePathRule>
  </RuleCollection>
</AppLockerPolicy>
```

I Allready set Up a New Test VM, tried to create the rules in gpedit, to create the rules in powershell. i tried it with gpupdate /force

Comment: Check that the applocked policy is applying at all with `Get-AppLockerPolicy -Effective`. To test a specific exe like chrome, export the current running policy with `Get-AppLockerPolicy -Effective -XML > c:\folder\file.xml`, then test whether chrome should be blocked by that policy with `Test-AppLockerPolicy -XmlPolicy c:\temp\file.xml -Path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe'`

Comment: @Cpt.Whale 
This is what i get for 'Get-AppLockerPolicy -Effective'  [link](https://i.imgur.com/nqPYALL.png)

Also i think it should be blocked:  [link](https://i.imgur.com/KoyJFDZ.png) but i can open it...

Comment: Check your applocker logs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/application-security/application-control/windows-defender-application-control/applocker/using-event-viewer-with-applocker . There are a handful of reasons why applocker may not be applying or enforcing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay ist solved, the Aplication Identity Service was set to Manuel on default. So i changed it to Automatic and Every thing worked finde after the start.

// As a note to my problem: It also didnt write in the Eventlog if the Service is Off ;)

Comment: You shouldn’t expect events with regards to a service if it’s not running so the absence of a event should be it’s own indicator that the service isn’t running.